# Creating UML diagram from specification

Tags: java, uml, class-diagram

I have to create/model a UML diagram from specification provided and was wondering if the diagram below correctly reflects the specification? Are all the associations correct? If so, I will be implementing the digram and start coding. Many thanks.

Specification:

A charitable trust has a name, a head office and a Chief Executive Officer (CEO) and a funds balance. The trust has two departments: Fund Raising and Grants. Each department has a director, a secretary, an office and a budget. The CEO, directors, and secretaries each have a name, address, ID and salary. Each office has an address and a phone number. The budget is used to fund the activities of the department. The Fund Raising department organizes events to promote awareness of the trust’s work. Any money raised is received by the trust. Each event has a name, description and cost. The Grants department awards money to worthy causes. Each cause has a name, description and amount requested. All requests are granted while the available budget of the relevant department is sufficient to cover the sums required. Each department must keep track of the number of activities it funds.

[image: UML class diagram]

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The one *important* problem with your diagram is this: stuff is repeated

1) **Secretary** is repeated (and so is Office, CEO, Director, etc.) That's just plain wrong, since there can only be a single class called **Secretary**.

This kind of stuff, however, you can easily address by just having a single box for **Secretary** and have both **GrantDepartment** and **FundRaisingDepartment** link to that.

2) you are not using sub-classes at all, and you really should. For instance, *Each department has a director, a secretary, an office and a budget* means there is a class called **Department** that has all of the above. **GrantDepartment** and **FundRaisingDepartment** are sub-classes of that (and thus inherit of all the properties), but they add more stuff as they need to (events and such)

Similary, *The CEO, directors, and secretaries each have a name, address, ID and salary.* - this means there's a class called **Employee** with all the above attributes, and **CEO**, **Director** etc. extend it. Alternatively (since there is no difference between CEO and Secretary other than the name of their job), **Employee** has all the above + **jobType**

and so on. Fix all that, post a comment here, and i'll glance again.

Comment: Could you please have a look, if these are better? Do I still need CEO, director and secretary classes? http://i.imgur.com/C7XzSAp.png?1 Thanks a lot.

Comment: If I'm creating a subclass of Grants and FundRaising, does the body contain no attributes at all? Thanks again

Comment: Better. But got to work on your arrows. "Has-a" (car has wheels) and "is-a" (car is a vehicle) are represented differently. Take a look here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_diagram